# angular ui-router $state change URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.4.8 and angular ui-router 0.2.18

My config:

```
  $stateProvider       
        .state('searchScreen', {
            url:'/offers/:mode?id',
            templateUrl: 'offerssearch',
            controller: 'SearchController as search'
        })
```

What I want to do is to bind a function changing url with button, here is my function:

```
search.createLink = function () {
    $state.go('searchScreen', {url:'/offers/link?id=234'});
}
```

and I want my URL look like this after function call:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/offers/link?id=234
```

But `/offers/link?id=234` is not appear in my URL `http://localhost:8080/#/offers/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't test, but I think you need to change your code to:

```
$state.go('searchScreen', { 'mode':'link', 'id': 234});
```

Comment: This is what I want! Thank You sooo much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this: `$state.go('searchScreen', {mode: 'link', id: 234})`